# Swift dictionary of dictionaries to SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift3, swifty-json

I have a dictionary of type `[Int:[Int:[Int:String]]]`.

I have the current code:

```
let myDict:[Int:[Int:[Int:String]]] = values
let jsonData = JSON(data: myDict)
```

However it does not work.

I have also tried this:

```
let myDict:[Int:[Int:[Int:String]]] = values
let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myDict)
let jsonData = JSON(data: archivedData)
```

The `jsonData` variable allways returns `nil` for both methods.

How would I create a `JSON` object of the dictionary type of `[Int:[Int:[Int:String]]]`?

Comment: Just change the "Int" types to "String" and it should work just fine.
and when you parse the json, convert back the strings to int.

let myDict: [String: [String: [String: String]]] = values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saeid said, yes, you should convert your integer keys to strings, since JSON RFC tells that object names should be of the string type.

[JSON RFC; Page 5. Section 4.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4)